# TypeError: Cannot find function splice in object

Tags: javascript

I have a numeric array inviteRowsTrue 4,5
It gets passed through an html form and is output as a string 4,5

The data arrives as 3 positions in the array:

```
0: 4

1: ,

2: 5

3: ,

4: 6
```

I am trying to remove all of the commas by looping through the array to look for commas and use the `.splice` method to remove each one so the `inviteRowsTrue` array ends up looking like:

```
0: 4

1: 5

2: 6
```

I keep getting:

> TypeError: Cannot find function splice in object error

My snippet:

```
    var inviteRowsTrue = calinvite.inviteRowsTrue; //data comes from an html form as 4,5 

     for(var p=1;p<inviteRowsTrue.length;p++){
     if(inviteRowsTrue[p] == ","){
       console.log("Found a comma");
       console.log("Before we remove the comma inviteRowsTrue contains: "+inviteRowsTrue);
       inviteRowsTrue.splice(p, 1);
       console.log("Removed that comma, now inviteRowsTrue contains: "+inviteRowsTrue); 
  
     }
  }
```

My console.log shows this output:

> Jul 14, 2019, 2:26:38 PM   DEBUG   Send invite
>
> Jul 14, 2019, 2:26:39 PM   DEBUG   Found a comma
>
> Jul 14, 2019, 2:26:39 PM   DEBUG   Before we remove the comma inviteRowsTrue contains: 4,5
>
> Jul 14, 2019, 2:26:39 PM   ERROR   TypeError: Cannot find function splice in object 4,5

What am I doing wrong?  Thanks!

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. What is in `inviteRowsTrue`?  Post the actual value in the question

Comment: Are you sure that `inviteRowsTrue` is an array? It looks like it could be a string, because it does not have brackets when outputted.

Comment: @WillardSolutions  Check the console output I provided, should clear that up (a downvote?)

Comment: @pydude Yes, if you check the console output you can see it is an array. I'm honestly not sure at this point if it is in string format or not. It starts as an array of numbers then it gets passed through an html form and when it is spit back out it is as you see in my OP.

Comment: You need to do more to prove it is an array. What does `console.log(Array.isArray(inviteRowsTrue))` output? I am sure it is *not* an array as you claim in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to apply a method `.splice()` to an `Object`. The `Object` does not have this method, only an `Array`. If the keys in the object are in order and don't matter to you, as you wrote in the post, you can just do this so to get the values of the object into an array:

```
inviteRowsTrue = Object.values(inviteRowsTrue);
```

Comment: That sounds like it would be perfect. But I get the following error:


TypeError: Cannot find function values in object function Object()

Comment: The code:

        var inviteRowsTrue = calinvite.inviteRowsTrue;  //data comes from an html form as 4,5

          console.log("Before: "+inviteRowsTrue);
          inviteRowsTrue = Object.values(inviteRowsTrue);
          console.log("After: "+inviteRowsTrue);

My console.log:

DEBUG
Send invite



DEBUG
Before: 4,5



ERROR
TypeError: Cannot find function values in object function Object() { [native code for Object.Object, arity=1] }. at generateCalInvite(Code:1863)

Thanks!

Comment: What is your `var inviteRowsTrue` at the beginning? Check `console.log(typeof inviteRowsTrue)` after `var inviteRowsTrue = calinvite.inviteRowsTrue;`

Comment: it shows String, so pydude was correct about the console.log notation. Is it possible or necessary to convert the entire array from string?

Comment: Oh, ok, I thought the object. Then just convert the string to an array `var inviteRowsTrue = calinvite.inviteRowsTrue.split('');` instead `Object.values()`

Answer (score 0):

Since your comments show that your Array is in fact not an Array but a String object, you can get rid of the commas with a one liner:

```
inviteRowsTrue = inviteRowsTrue.replace(/,/g, "")
```